# Visualforce doesn't reload in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I have a Visualforce page + component

```
<apex:component allowDml="true">

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!step.run}" rerender="form" status="loading" />
        ...
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

with and apex:commandButton calling Apex which when execute should reload the page.

But no matter what I return it's not reloading the page.

```
public override PageReference run() {
    ...
    return Page.samePage;
}
```

or

```
public override PageReference run() {
    ...
    return null;
}
```

or

```
public override PageReference run() {
    ...
    PageReference samePage = ApexPages.currentPage();
    samePage.setRedirect(true);
    return samePage;
}
```

Comment: with `reerender` attribute on command button, it performs a partial referesh of specified component/tag Id. But atleast there should be a redirection to new page with `return Page.samePage;`.

Comment: Not even that...

Comment: Does it matter if the redirect is executed from the component or visualforce, trying to think and isolate the problem here.

Comment: No that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and check if any of below options is working:

1. Remove rerender in button - this will not reload page normally also. (rerender="form")
2. Try returning PageRef.getUrl(). So return type of method will be string. And in Javascript, do window.open(url,"_self").

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why but this worked. Even with the `rerender`.

```
public override PageReference run() {
    ...
    PageReference samePage = Page.samePage;
    samePage.setRedirect(true);
    return samePage;
}
```